# Python Convert JSON payload to string

Tags: python, json, api, rest

Apologies if the question is basic. I am working on to convert json payload to pure string for signature purpose to make API POST
request.

I have define the json payload below:

```
def create_dca_trading_bot(bot_type, instrument_name, first_investment_time, investment_frequency_mode,
                           investment_frequency, investment_monthly_frequency, investment_currency,
                           max_no, total_investment, investment_duration, display_name, side, order_type, price,
                           quantity, stop_price,
                           take_profit_price, uuid, api_key, secret_key):

    method = 'private/create-trading-bot'

    payload = {
        "id": 1,
        "method": method,
        "params": {
            "bot_type": bot_type,
            "settings": {
                "instrument_name": str(instrument_name),
                "first_investment_time": str(first_investment_time),
                "investment_frequency_mode": str(investment_frequency_mode),
                "investment_frequency": str(investment_frequency),
                "investment_monthly_frequency": investment_monthly_frequency,
                "investment_currency": investment_currency,
                "side": str(side).upper(),
                "type": order_type,
                "max_no": max_no,
                "total_investment": total_investment,
                "investment_duration": investment_duration,
            },
            "display_name": display_name
        }
    }

    if price != '':
        payload['params']['settings']['price'] = price
    if quantity != '':
        payload['params']['settings']['quantity'] = quantity
    if stop_price != '':
        payload['params']['settings']['stop_price'] = stop_price
    if take_profit_price != '':
        payload['params']['settings']['take_profit_price'] = take_profit_price

    response = send_post_request_to_component_endpoint(payload, method, ip, port, uuid, api_key, secret_key)
    write_to_console(f"{method} response: {json.loads(response.text)}")
    return json.loads(response.text)
```

send post requset to component endpoint:

```
def send_post_request_to_component_endpoint(payload, method, ip, port, uuid, api_key=None, secret_key=None,
                                            account_uuid=None):
        payload = generate_sig(req=payload, component_api=False, api_key=api_key, secret_key=secret_key)
        write_to_console(f"{method} payload: {payload}")
        protocol = 'http'
        api_endpoint = f'{protocol}://{ip}:{port}/api/v2/{method}'
        headers = {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'gw-accountUuid': uuid
        }
        response = requests.post(url=api_endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers)
        write_to_console(f'{method} response: {response.text}')
        return response
```

Then to send out the request properly i will need to apply a siging logic , code as below.

```
def generate_sig(req, component_api, api_key=None, secret_key=None):
    param_str = ""
    max_level = 3

    if component_api:
        secret_key = 'SECRET_KEY'
        req["api_key"] = 'API_KEY'
    else:
        secret_key = secret_key
        req["api_key"] = api_key

    req['nonce'] = int(time.time() * 1000)

    def params_to_str(obj, level):
        if level >= max_level:
            return str(obj)

        return_str = ""
        for key in sorted(obj):
            return_str += key
            if isinstance(obj[key], list):
                for subObj in obj[key]:
                    return_str += params_to_str(subObj, ++level)
            else:
                return_str += str(obj[key])
        return return_str

    if "params" in req:
        param_str = params_to_str(req['params'], 0)
        write_to_console(f'param string: {param_str}')

    payload_str = req['method'] + str(req['id']) + req['api_key'] + param_str + str(req['nonce'])
    write_to_console(f'payload to string: {payload_str}')
    # write_to_console(f'payload_str: {payload_str}')
    req['sig'] = hmac.new(
        bytes(str(secret_key), 'utf-8'),
        msg=bytes(payload_str, 'utf-8'),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

    write_to_console(f'request: {req}')
    return req
```

However the param string now i get is sth like this below:

> param string: bot_typeDCAdisplay_nameDCA Trading botsettings{'instrument_name': 'ETH_USDT-dpre', 'first_investment_time': '1670670003000', 'investment_frequency_mode': 'FIXED_DURATION', 'investment_frequency': '5000', 'investment_monthly_frequency': '', 'investment_currency': 'ETH', 'side': 'SELL', 'type': 'MARKET', 'max_no': '1', 'total_investment': '', 'investment_duration': '', 'quantity': '1'}

In order to sign a message correctly, the param str i parse need to be like the format below...

> param string: bot_typeDCAdisplay_nameDCA Trading botsettingsinstrument_nameETH_USDT-dprefirst_investment_time1670670003000investment_frequency_modeFIXED_DURATION'investment_frequencyinvestment_monthly_frequencyinvestment_currencyETHsideSELLtypeMARKET'max_no1 total_investmentinvestment_durationquantity

Appreciate if you can kindly advise how i could resolve the issue.

Comment: `json.dumps` literally does convert JSON to string

Comment: @Gameplay It converts Python objects to JSON strings.

Comment: @Gameplay thanks for that, but json.dumps just converts the object in to JSON strings. I am currently looking a way to convert JSON object into strings..

Comment: You might have misunderstood something. There's nothing like a JSON object, if it is JSON it is a string (or something very similar). You can convert objects to JSON and JSON to objects, but JSON to strings makes sense in only one situation: The data inside the JSON is a string, but that does not seem to be the case here.